# Local data on Chromebook is locked because old password was forgotten

Tags: password-recovery, chromebook

I was helping my aunt over the phone with a computer problem, and long story short, she restarted her Chromebook, then realized that she didn't know her password (she's hibernated it since she got it).

I helped her reset her password, but now she's getting the error:

> "Your Google Account password has changed since the last time you signed in to this computer.  Because Chrome OS securely encrypts all your local data, you must enter the old password now to unlock that data."

As noted above however, she can't remember her old password. I understand why this is happening. The data is encrypted with her old password, so changing the password has no effect on that.

Is there any way to recover the old password? She thinks she wrote it down somewhere, but can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to recover the old password but "Local data" is usually just files saved in the Downloads folder as well as any Google Docs documents that were open for editing when there was no network connection.  As long as she's not concerned about these just ignore the message and log in with the new password.

Comment: Thanks. She's pretty computer illiterate, so she didn't know what local data she had. She was at home on WiFi though, so it should be fine then. Are downloads sync'd? That would probably be it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The Downloads folder is not synced so you should encourage your aunt to choose a folder within Google Drive if downloading something she might need later.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, my only experience with ChromeOS is the 2 hours I helped her set it up. Appreciate the tips.